# is there a way to make a list of two differnt type

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a list which is used to store data source of a data grid view
but the type of data source of data grid view is either "string" or "decimal"

I made this code

```
List<string> list1 = (List<string>)DataGridView.Datasource;
List<decimal> list2 = (List<decimal>)DataGridView.Datasource;
```

Two different type of list but I want to do this by declaring only one list
please help me..

Comment: What if you do it as List<object> ???

Comment: Why not make an object that represents your model instead of storing heterogeneous data in a list?

Comment: Can you tell me your DataGridView.datasource Type? Mean which type of object you have assigned to it?

Comment: is there any way to make list whose type is set according to type of datagrid datasource

Comment: @DanielMann has it right.

Comment: it gives error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to you can cast the data source to `IList` (the non-generic version).

```
IList data = (IList)DataGridView.Datasource;
```

This will allow you to access the items in the list as `object` types.

Another option would be to simply check the type of the list and act accordingly:

```
if(DataGridView.Datasource is List<string>)
{
    List<string> list = (List<string>)DataGridView.Datasource;
}
else
{
    List<decimal> list = (List<decimal>)DataGridView.Datasource;
}
```

This would be what you would do if you needed to have the objects typed as either a string or decimal, and couldn't work with them just as objects.

Comment: Good explanation as to why List<object> is not working. Second option is much simpler. Like it.

Answer (score 4):

use `List<object>` or worse `ArrayList` *(Don't use ArrayList please).*

```
List<object> list = (List<object>)DataGridView.datasource;
```

You can also look into `List<dynamic>`

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add("ABCD");
list.Add(1f);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
}
```

and the output would be:

```
System.Int32
System.String
System.Single
```

*(Not really sure if casting the DataSource from the GridView is possible for `List<dynamic>`)*

Comment: i made this code and its giving me error:                          List<decimal> li = new List<decimal>();
            li.Add(10);
            li.Add(10);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = li;

            List<object> ss = (List<object>)dataGridView1.DataSource;

Comment: `List` is not covariant, which is why this won't work.  You need to have both lists created as `List<object>` for this to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

If `DataGridView.datasource` is a `List<decimal>` then you will need to instantiate a new list and add each object manually:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
foreach(var item in DataGridView.datasource)
{
    myList.Add(item);
}
```

But as DanielMann says, you really should define a proper class to handle your two types of object, rather than just shoehorning them into a `List<object>`...

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else mentioned this yet...

There is also a CompositeCollection that you can use to store different types of objects in one IList compatible collection.

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherData { get; set; }
}

public class MyOtherObject()
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public object Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Main()
{
    private List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
    private List<MyOtherObject> moreObjects = new List<MyOtherObject>();

    public CompositeCollection TheCollection { get; private set; }

    public Main()
    {
        //mock adding data to the list
        objects.Add( ... );
        moreObjects.Add ( ... );

        //Build the composite collection
        TheCollection = new CompositeCollection
        {
            new CollectionContainer {Collection = objects},
            new CollectionContainer {Collection = moreObjects}                  
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<object> genericList = (List<object>)DataGridView.datasource;
```

would it solve the issue?

Here is sample conversion using LINQ.

```
List<decimal> dList = new List<decimal>();
List<object> oList = new List<object>();
oList = dList.Select(x => (object)x).ToList<object>();
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: please help me I really stuck on this